# Как создать окружение для деплоя?

Tags: apache, php, сеть, веб-программирование

Добрый день.
Я хочу прояснить следующий вопрос. Я только начинаю разрабатывать сайты с использованием PHP и мне хотелось бы иметь деплой-сервер на локальной виртуальной машине. Что лучше для этого использовать? Что знать, чтобы настроить его так, как мне нужно? Какие статьи/книги по сетям нужно прочесть для понимания своих действий?

Картина мне представляется следующая — локально (допустим, в `virtual box`) установлена убунта (опять-же, допустим), там стоит `apache/php/mysql`, я открываю в браузере `ip` своей виртуалки и получаю ответ апача оттуда. При этом для `mysql` использую что-то вроде `HeidiSQL` с подключением к виртуалке, как к удалённому серверу.

Есть общие папки, то есть разрабатывать я могу на клиенте, а смотреть уже на сервере. А идеальный был бы вариант с `git` — я в локальном репозитории разрабатываю что-то, а в удалённый на виртуалке заливаю какую-то ветку. Как-то так.

Answer (score 3):

Рекомендую [Denwer](http://www.denwer.ru/). Я начинал именно с него, а потом пришло понимание остальных моментов. Вся необходимая документация имеется на форуме целевого сайта.